# How to Use slideDown (or show) function on a table row?

Tags: jquery, animation, html-table, slidedown

I'm trying to add a row to a table and have that row slide into view, however the slidedown function seems to be adding a display:block style to the table row which messes up the layout.

Any ideas how to work around this?

Here's the code:

```
$.get('/some_url', 
  { 'val1': id },

  function (data) {
    var row = $('#detailed_edit_row');
    row.hide();
    row.html(data);
    row.slideDown(1000);
  }
);
```

Comment: Does it have to be a table?  Be a lot easier without the table I think.

Comment: `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` work on table rows and make a nice alternate visual effect (tested on Firefox only)

Answer (score 301, accepted):

Animations are not supported on table rows.

From "Learning jQuery" by Chaffer and Swedberg

---

> Table rows present particular
>   obstacles to animation, since browsers
>   use different values (table-row and
>   block) for their visible display
>   property.  The .hide() and .show()
>   methods, without animation, are always
>   safe to use with table rows.  As of
>   jQuery version 1.1.3, .fadeIn() and
>   .fadeOut() can be used as well.

---

You can wrap your td contents in a div and use the slideDown on that. You need to decide if the animation is worth the extra markup.

Comment: Works great! There's a minor other gotcha: You'll also have to animate cell padding if there is any. But that's not a big deal either.

Comment: You can animate the padding like this: `$('tr').find('td').animate({padding: '0px'}, {duration: 200});`

Comment: @Emily: Could you please point to specific lines of the jQuery source? I'm tempted to hack the source for my project.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I've found that using fadeIn / fadeOut is almost as good in most situations and it seems to work okay on table rows.

Comment: @PhilLaNasa At first I was like "Nah, that won't look good" but then I tried it and it looked really good! Thanks for the trip!

Comment: @PhilLaNasa do you find that on the fadeOut, it disappears too quickly without actually seeing any fading out?

Answer (score 159):

I simply wrap the tr dynamically then remove it once the slideUp/slideDown has complete. It's a pretty small overhead adding and removing one or a couple of  tags and then removing them once the animation is complete, I don't see any visible lag at all doing it.

**SlideUp**:

```
$('#my_table > tbody > tr.my_row')
 .find('td')
 .wrapInner('<div style="display: block;" />')
 .parent()
 .find('td > div')
 .slideUp(700, function(){
  
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    
 });
```

**SlideDown:**

```
$('#my_table > tbody > tr.my_row')
 .find('td')
 .wrapInner('<div style="display: none;" />')
 .parent()
 .find('td > div')
 .slideDown(700, function(){
  
  var $set = $(this);
  $set.replaceWith($set.contents());
    
 });
```

I have to pay tribute to fletchzone.com as I took his plugin and stripped it back to the above.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow this worked for me: row.find('td').wrapInner('<div style="display: none;" />').parent().prependTo('#MainTable > tbody').find('td > div').slideDown('slow', function(){                             var $set = $(this);$set.replaceWith($set.contents());});

Comment: Only issue is there's a slight delay between the cells.

Answer (score 41):

Here's a plug-in that I wrote up for this, it takes a little from Fletch's implementation, but mine is used solely to slide a row up or down (no inserting rows).

```
(function($) {
var sR = {
    defaults: {
        slideSpeed: 400,
        easing: false,
        callback: false     
    },
    thisCallArgs: {
        slideSpeed: 400,
        easing: false,
        callback: false
    },
    methods: {
        up: function (arg1,arg2,arg3) {
            if(typeof arg1 == 'object') {
                for(p in arg1) {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.eval(p) = arg1[p];
                }
            }else if(typeof arg1 != 'undefined' && (typeof arg1 == 'number' || arg1 == 'slow' || arg1 == 'fast')) {
                sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed = arg1;
            }else{
                sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed = sR.defaults.slideSpeed;
            }

            if(typeof arg2 == 'string'){
                sR.thisCallArgs.easing = arg2;
            }else if(typeof arg2 == 'function'){
                sR.thisCallArgs.callback = arg2;
            }else if(typeof arg2 == 'undefined') {
                sR.thisCallArgs.easing = sR.defaults.easing;    
            }
            if(typeof arg3 == 'function') {
                sR.thisCallArgs.callback = arg3;
            }else if(typeof arg3 == 'undefined' && typeof arg2 != 'function'){
                sR.thisCallArgs.callback = sR.defaults.callback;    
            }
            var $cells = $(this).find('td');
            $cells.wrapInner('<div class="slideRowUp" />');
            var currentPadding = $cells.css('padding');
            $cellContentWrappers = $(this).find('.slideRowUp');
            $cellContentWrappers.slideUp(sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed,sR.thisCallArgs.easing).parent().animate({
                                                                                                                paddingTop: '0px',
                                                                                                                paddingBottom: '0px'},{
                                                                                                                complete: function () {
                                                                                                                    $(this).children('.slideRowUp').replaceWith($(this).children('.slideRowUp').contents());
                                                                                                                    $(this).parent().css({'display':'none'});
                                                                                                                    $(this).css({'padding': currentPadding});
                                                                                                                }});
            var wait = setInterval(function () {
                if($cellContentWrappers.is(':animated') === false) {
                    clearInterval(wait);
                    if(typeof sR.thisCallArgs.callback == 'function') {
                        sR.thisCallArgs.callback.call(this);
                    }
                }
            }, 100);                                                                                                    
            return $(this);
        },
        down: function (arg1,arg2,arg3) {
            if(typeof arg1 == 'object') {
                for(p in arg1) {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.eval(p) = arg1[p];
                }
            }else if(typeof arg1 != 'undefined' && (typeof arg1 == 'number' || arg1 == 'slow' || arg1 == 'fast')) {
                sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed = arg1;
            }else{
                sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed = sR.defaults.slideSpeed;
            }

            if(typeof arg2 == 'string'){
                sR.thisCallArgs.easing = arg2;
            }else if(typeof arg2 == 'function'){
                sR.thisCallArgs.callback = arg2;
            }else if(typeof arg2 == 'undefined') {
                sR.thisCallArgs.easing = sR.defaults.easing;    
            }
            if(typeof arg3 == 'function') {
                sR.thisCallArgs.callback = arg3;
            }else if(typeof arg3 == 'undefined' && typeof arg2 != 'function'){
                sR.thisCallArgs.callback = sR.defaults.callback;    
            }
            var $cells = $(this).find('td');
            $cells.wrapInner('<div class="slideRowDown" style="display:none;" />');
            $cellContentWrappers = $cells.find('.slideRowDown');
            $(this).show();
            $cellContentWrappers.slideDown(sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed, sR.thisCallArgs.easing, function() { $(this).replaceWith( $(this).contents()); });

            var wait = setInterval(function () {
                if($cellContentWrappers.is(':animated') === false) {
                    clearInterval(wait);
                    if(typeof sR.thisCallArgs.callback == 'function') {
                        sR.thisCallArgs.callback.call(this);
                    }
                }
            }, 100);
            return $(this);
        }
    }
};

$.fn.slideRow = function(method,arg1,arg2,arg3) {
    if(typeof method != 'undefined') {
        if(sR.methods[method]) {
            return sR.methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1));
        }
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

**Basic Usage:**

```
$('#row_id').slideRow('down');
$('#row_id').slideRow('up');
```

**Pass slide options as individual arguments:**

```
$('#row_id').slideRow('down', 500); //slide speed
$('#row_id').slideRow('down', 500, function() { alert('Row available'); }); // slide speed and callback function
$('#row_id').slideRow('down', 500, 'linear', function() { alert('Row available'); }); slide speed, easing option and callback function
$('#row_id').slideRow('down', {slideSpeed: 500, easing: 'linear', callback: function() { alert('Row available');} }); //options passed as object
```

Basically, for the slide down animation, the plug-in wraps the contents of the cells in DIVs, animates those, then removes them, and vice versa for the slide up (with some extra steps to get rid of the cell padding). It also returns the object you called it on, so you can chain methods like so:

```
$('#row_id').slideRow('down').css({'font-color':'#F00'}); //make the text in the row red
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: What if I want to add/remove a group of Rows? I need to give a Master/Detail functionality

Comment: The callback function is firing immediately for me.

Comment: That's just plain showing off.  Works awesome though (though haven't tested the callback functionality).  One day I'll know enough jQuery to be able to reverse-engineer that.

Comment: FYI: This seems to break if the content of the target row is another table. I don't have time to go any further but what I've found is that it collapses the child table, sets all rows to hidden, adds some strange padding, and then it won't re-expand those rows once you call slideRow('down').

Comment: I had an issue with the `sR.thisCallArgs.callback` not keeping its value into the `setInterval` function. I fixed this with `var mycallback = sR.thisCallArgs.callback;` just before the `setInterval` call, then using `mycallback` instead of `sR.thisCallArgs.callback` inside the `setInterval` function

Comment: I ran into the same issues as others with child tables acting funny when calling slideRow('up') and then slideRow('down'). I figured out that it's because of the find('td') method being used twice in the plugin. I changed this to children('td') and the problems immediately went away.

For problems with th cells, simply update both instances of children('td') to children('td, th').

Comment: This works perfectly with preventing multiple clicks https://stackoverflow.com/a/28566136/2741616

Answer (score 5):

I neded a table with hidden rows that slide in and out of view on row click.

```js
$('.tr-show-sub').click(function(e) {  
    var elOne = $(this);
    $('.tr-show-sub').each(function(key, value) {
        var elTwoe = $(this);
        
        if(elOne.get(0) !== elTwoe.get(0)) {
            if($(this).next('.tr-sub').hasClass('tr-sub-shown')) {
                elTwoe.next('.tr-sub').removeClass('tr-sub-shown');
                elTwoe.next('tr').find('td').find('div').slideUp();
                elTwoe.next('tr').find('td').slideUp();
            }
        }
        
        if(elOne.get(0) === elTwoe.get(0)) {
            if(elOne.next('.tr-sub').hasClass('tr-sub-shown')) {
                elOne.next('.tr-sub').removeClass('tr-sub-shown');
                elOne.next('tr').find('td').find('div').slideUp();
                elOne.next('tr').find('td').slideUp();
            } else {
                elOne.next('.tr-sub').addClass('tr-sub-shown');
                elOne.next('tr').find('td').slideDown();
                elOne.next('tr').find('td').find('div').slideDown();
            }
        }
    })
});
```

```css
body {
        background: #eee;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
        margin: auto;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 10%;
    }
    
    table {
        background: white;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    table th {
        background: gray;
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    table th, td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    
    table .tr-show-sub {
        background: #EAEAEA;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    table .tr-sub td {
        display: none;
    }
    
    table .tr-sub td .div-sub {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table">
                <th>col 1</th>
                <th>col 2</th>
                <th>col 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="tr-show-sub">
                <td>col 1</td>
                <td>col 2</td>
                <td>col 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr-sub">
                <td colspan="5"><div class="div-sub">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis auctor tortor sit amet sem tempus rhoncus. Etiam scelerisque ligula id ligula congue semper interdum in neque. Vestibulum condimentum id nibh ac pretium. Proin a dapibus nibh. Suspendisse quis elit volutpat, aliquet nisi et, rhoncus quam. Quisque nec ex quis diam tristique hendrerit. Nullam sagittis metus sem, placerat scelerisque dolor congue eu. Pellentesque ultricies purus turpis, convallis congue felis iaculis sed. Cras semper elementum nibh at semper. Suspendisse libero augue, auctor facilisis tincidunt eget, suscipit eu ligula. Nam in diam at ex facilisis tincidunt. Fusce erat enim, placerat ac massa facilisis, tempus aliquet metus. Fusce placerat nulla sed tristique tincidunt. Duis vulputate vestibulum libero, nec lobortis elit ornare vel. Mauris imperdiet nulla non suscipit cursus. Sed sed dui ac elit rutrum mollis sed sit amet lorem. 
                </div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr-show-sub">
                <td>col 1</td>
                <td>col 2</td>
                <td>col 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr-sub">
                <td colspan="5"><div class="div-sub">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis auctor tortor sit amet sem tempus rhoncus. Etiam scelerisque ligula id ligula congue semper interdum in neque. Vestibulum condimentum id nibh ac pretium. Proin a dapibus nibh. Suspendisse quis elit volutpat, aliquet nisi et, rhoncus quam. Quisque nec ex quis diam tristique hendrerit. Nullam sagittis metus sem, placerat scelerisque dolor congue eu. Pellentesque ultricies purus turpis, convallis congue felis iaculis sed. Cras semper elementum nibh at semper. Suspendisse libero augue, auctor facilisis tincidunt eget, suscipit eu ligula. Nam in diam at ex facilisis tincidunt. Fusce erat enim, placerat ac massa facilisis, tempus aliquet metus. Fusce placerat nulla sed tristique tincidunt. Duis vulputate vestibulum libero, nec lobortis elit ornare vel. Mauris imperdiet nulla non suscipit cursus. Sed sed dui ac elit rutrum mollis sed sit amet lorem. 
                </div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>col 1</td>
                <td>col 2</td>
                <td>col 3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try wrapping the contents of the row in a `<span>` and having your selector be `$('#detailed_edit_row span');` - a bit hackish, but I just tested it and it works. I also tried the `table-row` suggestion above and it didn't seem to work.

**update**: I've been playing around with this problem, and from all indications jQuery needs the object it performs slideDown on to be a block element. So, no dice. I was able to conjure up a table where I used slideDown on a cell and it didn't affect the layout at all, so I am not sure how yours is set up. I think your only solution is to refactor the table in such a way that it's ok with that cell being a block, or just `.show();` the damn thing. Good luck.

Comment: You can't animate tr and td tags. You must wrap the contents of each td with a div, then animate the div, then hide/show the tr: `<td><div style="display:block">contents</div></td>`

Answer (score 4):

Select the contents of the row like this:

```
$(row).contents().slideDown();
```

[.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) - 
Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes.

Comment: You also have to select the column as well, so something like ```$('tr > td').contents().slideDown()```.  Make sure all the content inside the column is wrapped in a tag, i.e., having ```<td>Some text</td>``` won't work.  This is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit behind the times on answering this, but I found a way to do it :)

```
function eventinfo(id) {
    tr = document.getElementById("ei"+id);
    div = document.getElementById("d"+id);
    if (tr.style.display == "none") {
        tr.style.display="table-row";
        $(div).slideDown('fast');
    } else {
        $(div).slideUp('fast');
        setTimeout(function(){tr.style.display="none";}, 200);
    }
}
```

I just put a div element inside the table data tags. when it is set visible, as the div expands, the whole row comes down.
then tell it to fade back up (then timeout so you see the effect) before hiding the table row again :)

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 3):

Have a table row with nested table:

```
<tr class='dummyRow' style='display: none;'>
    <td>
        <table style='display: none;'>All row content inside here</table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

### To [slideDown](https://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) the row:

```
$('.dummyRow').show().find("table").slideDown();
```

**Note:** the row and it's content (here it is `"table"`) both should be [hidden](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) before animation starts.

---

### To [slideUp](https://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) the row:

```
$('.dummyRow').find("table").slideUp('normal', function(){$('.dummyRow').hide();});
```

The second parameter (`function()`) is a callback.

---

*Simple!!*

Note that there are also several [**options**](https://api.jquery.com/slidedown/#slideDown-options) that can be added as parameters of the slide up/down functions (the most common being durations of `'slow'` and `'fast'`).

Comment: Did you actually put your content between your rows, or was that a typo?

Answer (score 3):

I did use the ideas provided here and faced some problems. I fixed them all and have a smooth one-liner I'd like to share.

```
$('#row_to_slideup').find('> td').css({'height':'0px'}).wrapInner('<div style=\"display:block;\" />').parent().find('td > div').slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).parent().parent().remove();});
```

It uses css on the td element. It reduces the height to 0px. That way only the height of the content of the newly created div-wrapper inside of each td element matters.

The slideUp is on slow. If you make it even slower you might realize some glitch. A small jump at the beginning. This is because of the mentioned css setting. But without those settings the row would not decrease in height. Only its content would.

At the end the tr element gets removed.

The whole line only contains JQuery and no native Javascript.

Hope it helps.

Here is an example code:

```
    <html>
            <head>
                    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js">               </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                    <table>
                            <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                            <th>header_column 1</th>
                                            <th>header column 2</th>
                                    </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                    <tr id="row1"><td>row 1 left</td><td>row 1 right</td></tr>
                                    <tr id="row2"><td>row 2 left</td><td>row 2 right</td></tr>
                                    <tr id="row3"><td>row 3 left</td><td>row 3 right</td></tr>
                                    <tr id="row4"><td>row 4 left</td><td>row 4 right</td></tr>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <script>
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('#row2').find('> td').css({'height':'0px'}).wrapInner('<div style=\"display:block;\" />').parent().find('td > div').slideUp('slow',         function() {$(this).parent().parent().remove();});
    }, 2000);
                    </script>
            </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This post is exactly two years old. I have worked with jquery version 3.2.0. I have tested the code today with Chrome 73.0.3683.75 and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten around this by using the td elements in the row:

```
$(ui.item).children("td").effect("highlight", { color: "#4ca456" }, 1000);
```

Animating the row itself causes strange behaviour, mostly async animation problems.

For the above code, I am highlighting a row that gets dragged and dropped around in the table to highlight that the update has succeeded. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I'm getting `effect is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

I want to slide whole tbody and I've managed this problem by combining fade and slide effects.

I've done this in 3 stages (2nd and 3rd steps are replaced in case you want to slide down or up)

1. Assigning height to tbody,
2. Fading all td and th,
3. Sliding tbody.

Example of slideUp:

```
tbody.css('height', tbody.css('height'));
tbody.find('td, th').fadeOut(200, function(){
    tbody.slideUp(300)
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this affect the whole table, instead of just a particular row?

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with all the other solutions offered but ended up doing this simple thing that is smooth as butter.

Set up your HTML like so:

```
<tr id=row1 style='height:0px'><td>
  <div id=div1 style='display:none'>
    Hidden row content goes here
  </div>
</td></tr>
```

Then set up your javascript like so:

```
function toggleRow(rowid){
  var row = document.getElementById("row" + rowid)

  if(row.style.height == "0px"){
      $('#div' + rowid).slideDown('fast');
      row.style.height = "1px";   
  }else{
      $('#div' + rowid).slideUp('fast');
      row.style.height = "0px";   
  } 
}
```

Basically, make the "invisible" row 0px high, with a div inside.
Use the animation on the div (not the row) and then set the row height to 1px.

To hide the row again, use the opposite animation on the div and set the row height back to 0px.

Answer (score 1):

I liked the plugin that Vinny's written and have been using. But in case of tables inside sliding row (tr/td), the rows of nested table are always hidden even after slid up. So I did a quick and simple hack in the plugin not to hide the rows of nested table. Just change the following line

```
var $cells = $(this).find('td');
```

to

```
var $cells = $(this).find('> td');
```

which finds only immediate tds not nested ones. Hope this helps someone using the plugin and have nested tables.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add a comment to #Vinny's post but dont have the rep so have to post an answer...

Found a bug with your plugin - when you just pass an object in with arguments they get overwritten if no other arguments are passed in. Easily resolved by changing the order the arguments are processed, code below.
I've also added an option for destroying the row after closing (only as I had a need for it!): $('#row_id').slideRow('up', true); // destroys the row

```
(function ($) {
    var sR = {
        defaults: {
            slideSpeed: 400,
            easing: false,
            callback: false
        },
        thisCallArgs: {
            slideSpeed: 400,
            easing: false,
            callback: false,
            destroyAfterUp: false
        },
        methods: {
            up: function (arg1, arg2, arg3) {
                if (typeof arg2 == 'string') {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.easing = arg2;
                } else if (typeof arg2 == 'function') {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.callback = arg2;
                } else if (typeof arg2 == 'undefined') {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.easing = sR.defaults.easing;
                }
                if (typeof arg3 == 'function') {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.callback = arg3;
                } else if (typeof arg3 == 'undefined' && typeof arg2 != 'function') {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.callback = sR.defaults.callback;
                }
                if (typeof arg1 == 'object') {
                    for (p in arg1) {
                        sR.thisCallArgs[p] = arg1[p];
                    }
                } else if (typeof arg1 != 'undefined' && (typeof arg1 == 'number' || arg1 == 'slow' || arg1 == 'fast')) {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed = arg1;
                } else if (typeof arg1 != 'undefined' && (typeof arg1 == 'boolean')) {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.destroyAfterUp = arg1;
                } else {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed = sR.defaults.slideSpeed;
                }

                var $row = $(this);
                var $cells = $row.children('th, td');
                $cells.wrapInner('<div class="slideRowUp" />');
                var currentPadding = $cells.css('padding');
                $cellContentWrappers = $(this).find('.slideRowUp');
                $cellContentWrappers.slideUp(sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed, sR.thisCallArgs.easing).parent().animate({
                    paddingTop: '0px',
                    paddingBottom: '0px'
                }, {
                    complete: function () {
                        $(this).children('.slideRowUp').replaceWith($(this).children('.slideRowUp').contents());
                        $(this).parent().css({ 'display': 'none' });
                        $(this).css({ 'padding': currentPadding });
                    }
                });
                var wait = setInterval(function () {
                    if ($cellContentWrappers.is(':animated') === false) {
                        clearInterval(wait);
                        if (sR.thisCallArgs.destroyAfterUp)
                        {
                            $row.replaceWith('');
                        }
                        if (typeof sR.thisCallArgs.callback == 'function') {
                            sR.thisCallArgs.callback.call(this);
                        }
                    }
                }, 100);
                return $(this);
            },
            down: function (arg1, arg2, arg3) {

                if (typeof arg2 == 'string') {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.easing = arg2;
                } else if (typeof arg2 == 'function') {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.callback = arg2;
                } else if (typeof arg2 == 'undefined') {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.easing = sR.defaults.easing;
                }
                if (typeof arg3 == 'function') {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.callback = arg3;
                } else if (typeof arg3 == 'undefined' && typeof arg2 != 'function') {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.callback = sR.defaults.callback;
                }
                if (typeof arg1 == 'object') {
                    for (p in arg1) {
                        sR.thisCallArgs.eval(p) = arg1[p];
                    }
                } else if (typeof arg1 != 'undefined' && (typeof arg1 == 'number' || arg1 == 'slow' || arg1 == 'fast')) {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed = arg1;
                } else {
                    sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed = sR.defaults.slideSpeed;
                }

                var $cells = $(this).children('th, td');
                $cells.wrapInner('<div class="slideRowDown" style="display:none;" />');
                $cellContentWrappers = $cells.find('.slideRowDown');
                $(this).show();
                $cellContentWrappers.slideDown(sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed, sR.thisCallArgs.easing, function () { $(this).replaceWith($(this).contents()); });

                var wait = setInterval(function () {
                    if ($cellContentWrappers.is(':animated') === false) {
                        clearInterval(wait);
                        if (typeof sR.thisCallArgs.callback == 'function') {
                            sR.thisCallArgs.callback.call(this);
                        }
                    }
                }, 100);
                return $(this);
            }
        }
    };

    $.fn.slideRow = function (method, arg1, arg2, arg3) {
        if (typeof method != 'undefined') {
            if (sR.methods[method]) {
                return sR.methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I've also added in the children & th fixes

Answer (score 0):

If you need to slide and fade a table row at the same time, try using these:

```
jQuery.fn.prepareTableRowForSliding = function() {
    $tr = this;
    $tr.children('td').wrapInner('<div style="display: none;" />');
    return $tr;
};

jQuery.fn.slideFadeTableRow = function(speed, easing, callback) {
    $tr = this;
    if ($tr.is(':hidden')) {
        $tr.show().find('td > div').animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
    } else {
        $tr.find('td > div').animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, function(){
            $tr.hide();
            callback();
        });
    }
    return $tr;
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr.special').hide().prepareTableRowForSliding();
    $('a.toggle').toggle(function(){
        $button = $(this);
        $tr = $button.closest('tr.special'); //this will be specific to your situation
        $tr.slideFadeTableRow(300, 'swing', function(){
            $button.text('Hide table row');
        });
    }, function(){
        $button = $(this);
        $tr = $button.closest('tr.special'); //this will be specific to your situation
        $tr.slideFadeTableRow(300, 'swing', function(){
            $button.text('Display table row');
        });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hideTr(tr) {
  tr.find('td').wrapInner('<div style="display: block;" />').parent().find('td > div').slideUp(50, function () {
    tr.hide();
    var $set = jQuery(this);
    $set.replaceWith($set.contents());
  });
}

function showTr(tr) {
  tr.show()
  tr.find('td').wrapInner('<div style="display: none;" />').parent().find('td > div').slideDown(50, function() {
    var $set = jQuery(this);
    $set.replaceWith($set.contents());
  });
}
```

you can use these methods like:

```
jQuery("[data-toggle-tr-trigger]").click(function() {
  var $tr = jQuery(this).parents(trClass).nextUntil(trClass);
  if($tr.is(':hidden')) {
    showTr($tr);
  } else {
    hideTr($tr);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can be done if you set the td's in the row to display none at the same time you start animating the height on the row

```
tbody tr{
    min-height: 50px;
}
tbody tr.ng-hide td{
    display: none;
}
tr.hide-line{
    -moz-transition: .4s linear all;
    -o-transition: .4s linear all;
    -webkit-transition: .4s linear all;
    transition: .4s linear all;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;

    &.ng-hide { //angularJs specific
        height: 0;
        min-height: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PvwfK/136/

```
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' class='table01' id='form_table' style='width:100%;'>
<tr>
    <td style='cursor:pointer; width:20%; text-align:left;' id='header'>
        <label style='cursor:pointer;'> <b id='header01'>▲ Customer Details</b>

        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style='widtd:20%; text-align:left;'>
        <div id='content' class='content01'>
            <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' id='form_table'>
                <tr>
                    <td>A/C ID</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>3000/A01</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>A/C ID</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>3000/A01</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>A/C ID</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>3000/A01</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
$(function () {
$(".table01 td").on("click", function () {
    var $rows = $('.content01');
    if ($(".content01:first").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#header01").text("▲ Customer Details");
        $(".content01:first").slideDown();
    } else {
        $("#header01").text("▼ Customer Details");
        $(".content01:first").slideUp();
    }
});
```

});

Comment: This shows & hides a div containing a table. Not a table row as the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

This code works!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title></title>
        <script>
            function addRow() {
                $('.displaynone').show();
                $('.displaynone td')
                .wrapInner('<div class="innerDiv" style="height:0" />');
                $('div').animate({"height":"20px"});
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            .mycolumn{border: 1px solid black;}
            .displaynone{display: none;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table align="center" width="50%">
            <tr>
                <td class="mycolumn">Row 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="mycolumn">Row 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="displaynone">
                <td class="mycolumn">Row 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="mycolumn">Row 4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <button onclick="addRow();">add</button>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The plug offered by Vinny is *really* close, but I found and fixed a couple of small issues.

1. It greedily targeted td elements beyond just the children of the row being hidden. This would have been kind of ok if it had then sought out those children when showing the row. While it got close, they all ended up with "display: none" on them, rendering them hidden.
2. It didn't target child th elements at all.
3. For table cells with lots of content (like a nested table with lots of rows), calling slideRow('up'), regardless of the slideSpeed value provided, it'd collapse the view of the row as soon as the padding animation was done. I fixed it so the padding animation doesn't trigger until the slideUp() method on the wrapping  is done.

   ```
   (function($){
       var sR = {
           defaults: {
               slideSpeed: 400
             , easing: false
             , callback: false
           }
         , thisCallArgs:{
               slideSpeed: 400
             , easing: false
             , callback: false
           }
         , methods:{
               up: function(arg1, arg2, arg3){
                   if(typeof arg1 == 'object'){
                       for(p in arg1){
                           sR.thisCallArgs.eval(p) = arg1[p];
                       }
                   }else if(typeof arg1 != 'undefined' && (typeof arg1 == 'number' || arg1 == 'slow' || arg1 == 'fast')){
                       sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed = arg1;
                   }else{
                       sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed = sR.defaults.slideSpeed;
                   }

                   if(typeof arg2 == 'string'){
                       sR.thisCallArgs.easing = arg2;
                   }else if(typeof arg2 == 'function'){
                       sR.thisCallArgs.callback = arg2;
                   }else if(typeof arg2 == 'undefined'){
                       sR.thisCallArgs.easing = sR.defaults.easing;    
                   }
                   if(typeof arg3 == 'function'){
                       sR.thisCallArgs.callback = arg3;
                   }else if(typeof arg3 == 'undefined' && typeof arg2 != 'function'){
                       sR.thisCallArgs.callback = sR.defaults.callback;    
                   }
                   var $cells = $(this).children('td, th');
                   $cells.wrapInner('<div class="slideRowUp" />');
                   var currentPadding = $cells.css('padding');
                   $cellContentWrappers = $(this).find('.slideRowUp');
                   $cellContentWrappers.slideUp(sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed, sR.thisCallArgs.easing, function(){
                       $(this).parent().animate({ paddingTop: '0px', paddingBottom: '0px' }, {
                           complete: function(){
                               $(this).children('.slideRowUp').replaceWith($(this).children('.slideRowUp').contents());
                               $(this).parent().css({ 'display': 'none' });
                               $(this).css({ 'padding': currentPadding });
                           }
                       });
                   });
                   var wait = setInterval(function(){
                       if($cellContentWrappers.is(':animated') === false){
                           clearInterval(wait);
                           if(typeof sR.thisCallArgs.callback == 'function'){
                               sR.thisCallArgs.callback.call(this);
                           }
                       }
                   }, 100);                                                                                                    
                   return $(this);
               }
             , down: function (arg1, arg2, arg3){
                   if(typeof arg1 == 'object'){
                       for(p in arg1){
                           sR.thisCallArgs.eval(p) = arg1[p];
                       }
                   }else if(typeof arg1 != 'undefined' && (typeof arg1 == 'number' || arg1 == 'slow' || arg1 == 'fast')){
                       sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed = arg1;
                   }else{
                       sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed = sR.defaults.slideSpeed;
                   }

                   if(typeof arg2 == 'string'){
                       sR.thisCallArgs.easing = arg2;
                   }else if(typeof arg2 == 'function'){
                       sR.thisCallArgs.callback = arg2;
                   }else if(typeof arg2 == 'undefined'){
                       sR.thisCallArgs.easing = sR.defaults.easing;    
                   }
                   if(typeof arg3 == 'function'){
                       sR.thisCallArgs.callback = arg3;
                   }else if(typeof arg3 == 'undefined' && typeof arg2 != 'function'){
                       sR.thisCallArgs.callback = sR.defaults.callback;    
                   }
                   var $cells = $(this).children('td, th');
                   $cells.wrapInner('<div class="slideRowDown" style="display:none;" />');
                   $cellContentWrappers = $cells.find('.slideRowDown');
                   $(this).show();
                   $cellContentWrappers.slideDown(sR.thisCallArgs.slideSpeed, sR.thisCallArgs.easing, function() { $(this).replaceWith( $(this).contents()); });

                   var wait = setInterval(function(){
                       if($cellContentWrappers.is(':animated') === false){
                           clearInterval(wait);
                           if(typeof sR.thisCallArgs.callback == 'function'){
                               sR.thisCallArgs.callback.call(this);
                           }
                       }
                   }, 100);
                   return $(this);
               }
           }
       };

       $.fn.slideRow = function(method, arg1, arg2, arg3){
           if(typeof method != 'undefined'){
               if(sR.methods[method]){
                   return sR.methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
               }
           }
       };
   })(jQuery);
   ```

Comment: @circuitry, did you have something specific to offer or is your criticism sufficient?

Comment: @Oregoneff Just being honest. I'm looking for something simpler. It shouldn't take 109 lines of code to slide a table row.

Comment: @circuitry, it doesn't get simpler if you want to be able to use as a plugin (and not just engage in the bad practice of use-specific code) with the ability to control speed, easing, and have callbacks on a customizable basis. Since this is something you'd include in your code library and can be used for *any* implementation that requires expand/collapse table rows, I'm not sure why it matters that it's 109 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Quick/Easy Fix:

Use JQuery [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show/hide the rows onclick of either Row or an Anchor.

A function will need to be written to identify the rows you would like hidden, but toggle creates the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: I think that this was suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4393158/3908170) answer already...