# jQuery append row to table and slideDown effect is corrupting the table row

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to append a row to a table and to apply the slideDown effect on just that row as it loads in (for context, the results are being retrieved via Ajax and are added when received).

When I add the row without effect the table forms correctly.  When I use fadeIn as an effect, the table still forms correctly.  However, when I use slideDown as the effect, the table row becomes "corrupted" and the columns fail to line-up correctly.

I have a table like this:

```
<div id="results">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td></tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

and my Javascript looks like this:

```
$("<tr><td>val1</td><td>val2</td></tr>")
 .hide().slideDown("slow")
 .appendTo("#results table tbody");
```

I've also tried this:

```
$("#results table tbody")
  .append("<tr><td>val1</td><td>val2</td></tr>")
  .find("tr:last").hide().slideDown("slow");
```

The second option here shows the effect correctly, but as I mentioned garbles the table.

Is this possible?

I'm testing this in Chrome 4 (could that be the issue?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - How to Use slideDown (or show) function on a table row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a duplicate of [How to Use slideDown (or show) function on a table row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row)

The short answer is that jQuery animations don't work well on things that aren't block elements, and especially don't work on table rows and cells.

Comment: `$("table tr:first").effect("highlight",{},3000);` worked for me.