# jQuery why does $('tr').slideDown('slow'); break table layout?

Tags: jquery, html-table

Can anyone tell me why when using `$('tr').slideDown('slow');` it causes the table row to forget its width, height etc.

and if there is a way to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - How to Use slideDown (or show) function on a table row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Animations are not supported on table rows.
Emily typed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row/920480#920480)
you can put the content in a div inside the td and doing a slideDown on the div...

Answer (score 2):

I fixed same problem with adding div into current table row->cells(TR->TD).

My sample table:

```
<table>
<tr id='row_1'>
   <td><div>element 1</div></td>
   <td><div>element 2</div></td>
   <td><div>element 3</div></td>
</tr>
<tr id='row_2'>
   <td><div>element 1</div></td>
   <td><div>element 2</div></td>
   <td><div>element 3</div></td>
</tr>
<tr id='row_3'>
   <td><div>element 1</div></td>
   <td><div>element 2</div></td>
   <td><div>element 3</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then if you need this make:

```
$('#row_1').slideDown(); // Make this onclick or some other event
$('#row_1').slideUp(); // Make this onclick or some other event
```

You must do:

```
$('#row_1 div').slideDown(); // Make this onclick or some other event
$('#row_1 div').slideUp(); // Make this onclick or some other event
```

Some lines of code more, but didnt found other way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because jQuery animation code tends to assume it can use `display: block` for elements that seem like they're block-level elements. For a `<tr>` that'd be bad, because it wants to be `display: table-row` (I think; something like that).