# How to nicely remove a table tr with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to smoothly remove the first tr of my table by doing:

```
$("#table_id").children().first().fadeOut('slow');
```

But the tr just disappears without any nice effect. Actually, this is not working either for any jQuery effect (slideUp, animate, hide('slide', ...), etc).

Any thoughts of how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this on divs before - not sure if it's the same issue with a tr. However, try putting `filter:inherit;` on the tr.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 apparently doesn't handle the smooth fade and exhibits the behaviour you describe, whereas Chrome worked fine.

Adding `filter: inherit` inline seems to do the trick, although it's a dirty workaround: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yYVUq/)

If you've got nested tables, then you can use [eq(0)](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of `:first-child` to match the specific row:

```
$("#table_id tr:eq(0)").fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Actually, my table structure is more like [this]http://jsfiddle.net/5YjKV/, and see what happens. All the tr are hidden now :-/

Comment: Thanks. It sort of worked, but I had to wrap the elements with <div> to make slideUp work: http://jsfiddle.net/NmQFJ/

Comment: @Sam: Animations (other than fadeIn and fadeOut) [aren't supported on table rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row), so that'll be why.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not set `jQuery.fx.off` to true since it will disable all of the jquery animations.