# jQuery table row expand/collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, collapsable

I've got a table and it has rows that are collapsible when clicked on the table heading.

Problem is it doesn't seem to be very smooth, there's a lag and jump once I click on the header and when the content shows. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[See example build »](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/66414/collapse/index.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, table rows does not animate (with jquery) - see this related question on SO: [How to Use slideDown (or show) function on a table row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row)

Work-around will be to use div based layout or try out wrapping td content into divs and animating those divs - see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Krpn/2/). Of course, you have to adjust the css.