# using slidedown() to show an newly appended element

Tags: jquery, forms

I am trying to create a fieldset that will append a file input field to a div AND use the slidedown() function to show the newly created field. This simple code does exactly what I need to do but I can't figure out how to integrate the slidedown action. I did come up with a solution that is almost there by hiding div#add_pic, appending the new field, then slidedown()ing it but it looks really bad. Does anyone have an elegant solution for this? Thanks!!

```
function add_file_input() {

$('div#add_pic').append("<label>Artist Pic:</label><input type='file' name='pics[]'><br     />");

}

$(document).ready(function(){

$('a#add_field').click(add_file_input);

})
```

Comment: As an aside: `$('a#add_field')` should probably be: `$('#add_field')`.  An id is unique so there's no need to include anything else and jQuery will be able to find it faster (using `document.getElementById()`) if there is nothing other than just the ID in the selector.  Same with `$('div#add_pic')` should be `$('#add_pic')`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Im not sure of the exact HTML Layout but I would wrap what you are appending in another div that is hidden then slide the newly added div down.  like this

```
function add_file_input() {

   $('div#add_pic').append("<div class="addedDiv" style="display:none"><label>Artist Pic:</label><input type='file' name='pics[]'><br     /></div>");
   $('div.addedDiv').slideDown("slow");

}

$(document).ready(function(){

   $('a#add_field').click(add_file_input);

})
```

Comment: Wow, that worked brilliantly. I thought I would have to add a :last selector so that it would only slideDown the last div added but it works just as you described. When I started messing with counters I had a feeling I was doing it wrong. Thanks a lot John!

Comment: This looks very elegant.  I don't know if anyone is around since this post is 2 years old.  But I am trying to append data to a table layout of items added to  a shopping cart.  Any way to do this?  Putting tr and td in a  div isn't going to work.  Thanks!

Comment: @Chris22  your asking if its possible to add a tr and have it animate to slide down?

Comment: @Chris if you are trying to animate a tr...then here is a useful link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row