# jQuery - hiding/collapsing a <table> row

Tags: jquery, css

I want table rows to disappear (by animating their height to 0px and opacity to 0). I'm using the following

```
$('#somecellelement').closest('tr').children('td').css('overflow','hidden');
$('#somecellelement').closest('tr').children('td').animate({
    height: '0px',
    opacity: 0
},500);
```

Where `#somecellelement` is something contained in cells of rows I want hidden. `Opacity` is animating correctly but the table row doesn't get smaller. If I set `height: 500px` then it works, but I need the row to disappear.

I cannot remove the element from DOM, though, due to scripts expecting values from form elements in those rows.

Comment: Is there a reason not stated that you are animating the td element instead of #somecellelement directly? The problem you're having is tr and td aren't set to display type of block which causes an issue with trying to set their height to 0.

Comment: #somecellelement is not supposed to be animated. it's just an <input> whose parent row needs to be hidden.

Comment: Well, you're going to have issues achieving a height animation on a tr or td is why I asked, they just don't appear to work. The 2 solutions posted below are I assume not doing what you're looking for specifically. I'm reading it that you want it to animate the height up until the row disappears.

Comment: Yes, exactly. And I need to use <table> because it's actual tabular data. Oh well if it can't be done, display:none will have to do

Comment: Took a shot at an answer assuming you can wrap the contents of the <td> in a <div>

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can apply a `<div>` within each `<td>` element, then you can animate them properly. jQuery does not apply height animations to `<tr>` and `<td>`. The height animations only work on elements with `display: block` set, I believe.

A small change:

```
$('#somecellelement').closest('tr').children('td').children('div').animate(
    {height: '0px',
     opacity: 0}, 500);
```

Full sample here:
http://jsfiddle.net/PvwfK/

Comment: Actually height animations work in my case, but only when I set them to something larger than they are initially. My problem seems to be that table rows overflow can't be set to hidden for some reason.

Answer (score 7):

As Doozer Blake's answer says, you cannot apply jQuery animations to `<td>` and `<tr>` elements. I also don't like the idea of adding a `<div>` element to every cell in the table in advance, because in large tables it can hurt performance.

However, you can use jQuery's `wrapInner` function to dynamically wrap the contents of the `<td>`, only when you need to animate the row:

```
$('#somecellelement')
    .closest('tr')
    .children('td')
    .wrapInner('<div class="td-slider" />')
    .children(".td-slider")
    .slideUp();
```

### A word about padding

If your `<td>` elements have padding, they also need to be animated for a complete collapsing effect. This can be done easily with CSS3 transitions:

```
$('#somecellelement').closest('tr').addClass('collapsed');
```

And the CSS:

```
td {padding:10px; transition:padding 1s;}
.collapsed > td {padding:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are animating the children, animate the `<tr>`

```
$('#somecellelement').closest('tr').animate({
    height: '0px',
    opacity: 0
},500);
```

Comment: Same thing, doesn't work. I tried animating children because I read that there are problems with animating table rows and I forgot to put it back the way it was.