# slideDown forces display:block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use the following code to slide down a row, but jQuery enforces `display: block` on the row, when it's supposed to be `table-row`, breaking the styling.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ay3z/

I manually set it to `table-row` after it's complete, but that is horrendous. How can I work around this?

```
<style>
table {
    margin: 25px;
}
tr {
    background-color: #c00;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td style="display:none;">1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQ:

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    var row = $(this);
    var visibleLength = row.find("td:visible").length;
    var hiddenLength = row.find("td:not(:visible)").length;
    var drillRow = $("<tr/>").addClass("drillDownRow");
    var drillColumn = $("<td/>").attr("colspan", visibleLength);
    var drillHidden = $("<td/>").attr("colspan", hiddenLength).css({display: "none"});

    drillColumn.html("test <b>2</b>... ok");

    drillRow.hide().append(drillColumn).append(drillHidden).insertAfter(row);
    drillRow.slideDown("slow",function() {$(this).css({display: "table-row"})});
});
```

Comment: Is there any way you could not use a table for this?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/467336/681807

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row

Comment: @Rory: unfortunately no, it's a `dataTable` I have to add extra contents to rows as they're clicked. I hate `table`s :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `animate` method instead of `slideDown`.  You'll need to do a bit more manual definition of the effect you want, but it won't introduce the `display:block` that's giving you trouble.

Quoted from http://api.jquery.com/animate/:

> Note: Unlike shorthand animation methods such as .slideDown() and
>   .fadeIn(), the .animate() method does not make hidden elements visible
>   as part of the effect. For example, given
>   $('someElement').hide().animate({height:'20px'}, 500), the animation
>   will run, but the element will remain hidden.

Answer (score 4):

```
 $el.slideDown(function() {$(this).css('display', '');});
```

Comment: Below @redlena gave a correct answer. But in real life, often simple solutions that work outweigh the right solutions. This one is simple and it works!