# Animating a div inside td results in erratic behaviour in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm building a rather complicated UI widget which has some problems in Chrome. I was able to isolate the problem and am showcasing it at http://jsfiddle.net/8Kb3B/

I have a `div` inside a `td`, and I'm trying to toggle the div with jQuery's `.animate()`. What happens in Chrome is that the `td` doesn't grow back when the `div` is returned to its original width. Also, if you pay close attention to the end of the "hide" animation, you'll see that the `td`'s width briefly flashes at the width of the content of the `div`, which I find weird.

The same thing happens when `.toggle(delay)` is used. If I use `.toggle()` without a delay, the whole thing works as intended.

The animation works properly in Mozilla's offerings and even in IE.

Am I missing something really simple here?

Comment: Maybe is related or not, but some time ago, this other question helped me with animations and tables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row

Answer (score 1):

I try from my side may be that's help you. Write like this for `webkit` based browsers:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    td {
    padding-right:2px;
    }
    span{
    left:5px;
    position:absolute;
    }
    #content {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    height:20px;
    display:table;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
   }
}
```

Check this for more http://jsfiddle.net/8Kb3B/3/

Comment: The jsFiddle I provided is a really, really stripped-down version of what I'm actually working with and embedding additional spans and table-like divs is highly impractical for my purposes to say the least. I was just wondering, since my code example was so simple, that there might be a bug somewhere, be it jQuery or Chrome.