# Block double click event in entire application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I want to block double-click application globally in ASP.NET application. I know few ways but that is something I need to write code on each page/event click. Is there any way to handle this globally and I do not need to write code on each page/event click.

Few days back we have implemented to block back button by using history *history.pushstate* in *site.master*. I was wondering if I can do something similar to block double-click as well.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11621701/4248328

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent a double-click using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621652/how-to-prevent-a-double-click-using-jquery)