# .click handler called twice when I double-click - have already disabled dblClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot seem to prevent TWO click events being fired when the user double-clicks an element.  I've tried both jQuery (.click) and inline (onclick) handlers, and I have disabled the dblClick event using this:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $("*").on("dblclick", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

I don't really want to add flag/timeouts everywhere as I have many click handlers and I need to disable double-clicks across the board generically...

JSFiddle here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/s0oteh84/26/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621652/how-to-prevent-a-double-click-using-jquery

Comment: First fix the typo, $('#my_button1').one should be $('#my_button1').on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent a double-click using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621652/how-to-prevent-a-double-click-using-jquery)

Comment: the .one is intentional, to ensure it's only called once

Answer (score 0):

Use follwing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("*").on("dblclick", function(e){
    return false;
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

It's not even entering in your

```
$("*").on("dblclick", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

better use timeout of around `300ms` to differentiate between the clicks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by showing a temporary div above all the elements to receive the second click within a 400ms timeout.

```
jQuery("*").on("click", function(e){
  if (jQuery(this).attr('id') != "double_click_div") {
    jQuery('#double_click_div').css('display', 'block');
    setTimeout(function () {
      jQuery('#double_click_div').css('display', 'none');
    }, 400);
  }
  else
    alert('caught!');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s0oteh84/34/