# Prevention of double submission

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am currently have problems with double submissions with my local website. Most of my users uses slow internet connection. They always double clicking the button. I placed a disable button events on my ajax but on slow connection it seems that it does not work.

Here is my code I used:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'submit-application-fee-details.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'TEXT',
    data: {applno : applno, feecode : feecode, feeamt : feeamt, auditky : auditky, uid: uid, feepd : feepd, dedto : dedto},
    beforeSend: function(){
        document.getElementById("confirmsubmit").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("confirmsubmit").innerHTML = 'Submit &nbsp; <div class="spinner-border text-light" role="status"> <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></div>';
    },
    success: function(response) {
       if(response == 'Approved Application' || response == 'Updated' || response == 'Inserted'){
            document.getElementById("update").classList.add("button-hidden");
            document.getElementById("cancel").classList.add("button-hidden");

            initialize_form();
            display_table();
            clear_fee_info_form();

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("body").offset().top
            }, 100,
            'linear');

            if(response == 'Approved Application'){
                show_alert('Fee Submit', "Application is approved. Details cannot be updated.", 'warning');
            }
            else if(response == 'Updated'){
                show_alert('Fee Submit', "Fee has been updated.", 'success');
            }
            else if(response == 'Inserted'){
                show_alert('Fee Submit', "Fee has been assigned.", 'success');
            }
        }
        else{
            show_alert('Fee Submit Error', response, 'error');
        }
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');

        document.getElementById("confirmsubmit").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("confirmsubmit").innerHTML = 'Submit'; 
    }
});
```

As you can see I added **beforeSend** function on my ajax. On my tests it always disabled the button before sending the data and after inserting the data the button will be enabled. However, my users when they ran the website on a slow internet connection the button does not disabling. Is there a better way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Is the "php" tag really needed?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry, I accidentally added the PHP tag

Comment: No worries, and thanks. I can't code JS worth to save my life *lol!* but I do know how to find stuff on the web though :) Have a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11621652/1415724) here on Stack. There might be something in there you could use. I found that when searching for "avoid double click jquery". Maybe I could have used "prevent" instead of "avoid" but that should get you going, I hope.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner before posting the question I tried adding all sorts of disabling events like disabling the button upon clicking. I found out that using beforeSend is much cleaner and efficient than putting events on a button.

Comment: You should just `Element.disabled = true;` on your click or submit Event, not in your AJAX.

Comment: @StackSlave I tried that but still my users seem to find a way to double click the submit button

Comment: @EncoreLeasingandFinanceCor ah ok. Well, I wish you the best with this, cheers :) I'm a serverside coder. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run the disabled = true code even before calling to the ajax method. Maybe some network resolution or something is delaying beforeSend.

You can also implement a javascript global boolean variable that (locks) disables the ajax invocation.

But always even before calling to ajax.

**Edit**: also, if the form has the submit button disabled, if the user press enter on some places, then the form can be submitted.

Comment: What do you mean by javascript lock variable?

Comment: :) a simple boolean variable that locks further sendings. Also, did you know that if a user press enter in the form the submission is done, even with the submit button disabled?

Comment: Yes I know that. I will try it and get back to you. Thank you