# Prevent multiple clicks on link while leaving page in JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link with some parameter which loads another page like:

```html
    <a href="/cart.php?action=save&amp" class="prevent_doubleclick">save</a>
```

When someone clicks on the link, it will change the text from `save` to `please wait...`.

Meanwhile the browser is loading the `/cart.php` page but I'm still on the current page which takes around 3 to 5 seconds and the user is able to click 10 more times on the link which will result in sending the parameters many times and each time a new item is saved.

I can't disable the `click` `event` with `.one()` or `return false` or `unbind` since the user `triggers` the `click` the first time by actually clicking on the link and I `trigger` a second `click` `event` after 2 seconds by code. So if I disable the click event after the user has clicked the link then my `$('.element').trigger('click');` won't work anymore.

Any ideas on how this is doable?

Comment: Why do you do `$('.element').trigger('click');` after a couple seconds instead of letting the click event operate normally?

Comment: @CertainPerformance because it has check some data and do some other work.

Comment: I think your answer is already exist on this page.. [ How to prevent a double-click using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621652/how-to-prevent-a-double-click-using-jquery)

Comment: @DevMan Can you explain why a single click can't manage that? It's not clear what your need for that logic is at the moment

Comment: @John NO. There it disables the button after the first click. Exactly what I didn't want.

Comment: @DevMan So you want the link/button click to do one thing the first time it is clicked and then another thing the 2nd time it is clicked (while the first click action hasn't resolved)?  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry but it is how it is. Trust me I have thought about it alot but it's not a simple shop app but some kind of other app and I can't enclose all aspects of it. Many people are trying to find a solution already. We can't change the logic and have to find a solution as it ist.

Comment: @raddevus No. After it's clicked, it takes some time for the new page to load but I'm still on the old page. So the user can click 10 more times on the link. Which will send the data multiple times.

Comment: '*the browser is loading the /cart.php page but I'm still on the current page which takes around 3 to 5 seconds*' That is the issue you should be looking to solve. Anything around preventing double clicks is a band-aid to the actual problem of a painfully slow server.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is all clear to me but in certain situations you have to find a temp solution.

Comment: Doesn't just moving the onclick code to client-side function (JavaScript) allow you to separate out exactly what you want to do?  Instead of firing the request for the link (/cart.php?action=save&amp) directly you can move it to a JS function, do the work you want to do (disable the button or whatever) then fire the request for the link.  Doesn't that solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener [, options]);
```

with the `once` option

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

I hope I could help

Answer (score 0):

Rather than triggering the click the second time, you could change the `window.location`, and set a flag when clicked:

```
let clicked = false;
$('.prevent_doubleclick').on('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (clicked) return;
  clicked = true;

  /* do whatever stuff you need to do here */

  setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.href = '/cart.php?action=save&amp';
  }, 2000);
});
```