# Slide a table up/down with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to close/open a table with animation. I tried using jQuery for this purpose just to discover that jquery cannot perform slideUp/Down on tables.
Sure i can use `.wrap()` to enclose that table in a div but it is clumsy and gives me bugs sometimes

Is there any other option? 
Also, jquery animations are not smooth; how to achieve smooth animations like in http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/animatedcollapse.htm

Comment: ever looked at [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)? put your table within this `<div>` and you'll be able to slide the table

Comment: As i said in my question, i have tried wrapping tables in div but i have to dynamically to do so to all tables. And i would like to avoid it

Comment: in fact the slideToggle can give some problems sometimes.. I had the same problem that u have, but I solved it using changing my table for a <div> and using slideUp and slideDown solved my problem. I just had to add more 'if' conditions. When I was doing it in a table, I coudnt set the speed...

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - How to Use slideDown (or show) function on a table row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row)

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hWFy6/2/)

```
<button id="hidr">Hide</button>
<button id="showr">Show</button>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
    $("#hidr").click(function () {
      $("table").hide("fast");
    });
    $("#showr").click(function () {
      $("table").show("fast");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i do NOT want to wrap the tables with div because i will have to do it dynamically for all tables (due to limitations of script i'm working on)

Comment: that's the problem. Using slideToggle() on table/table rows doesn't work. There is no animation
uhm...will it be possible with other frameworks?

Comment: yes that. looks good but the content seems squeezed during the animation and the animation is horizontal not vertical. I need vertical (up/down, as said in title)