# show hide rows on dynamic table

Tags: jquery

```
<table> //big table
       <tr >
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
       </tr>    

        <tr >
        <th colspan='4'>
                 <div> 
                       <table> //small table
                               <tr>
                                      <td></td> <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                               </tr>
                       </table>
                 </div>
            </th>   
       </tr>
</table>
```

Each even row of big dynamic table has a table inside that explains data about the row befor(odd row). I want to initially hide hide all even rows (rows which has a table inside).

On click event of each odd row I want to hide/unhide the next even row (which has a table inside)

```
this is my ajax calls

    $.get("invoice_ajax.php", 
    {"q": test},
    function(data) 
    {
    $('#balance').html = data;
```

with this code I'm trying to slide even rows.

```
$('#balance').on("click","table",function(event) 
            {
                event.stopPropagation();
                var $target = $(event.target);
                if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 ) 
                {
                    $target.slideUp();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $target.closest("tr").next().find("div").slideToggle();
                }                    
            });
```

At first Ajax call everything works fine and each click shows or hides the next row but on second ajax call on click event of odd row (shows and hides next row) on third call (show, hide, show) after forth call(show, hide, show,hide) and it goes on and on increases with every ajax calls .

Also I don't know how to initially hide even rows.

EDIT: the page in a nutshell - http://pastebin.com/QtTxXnzX

Comment: Maybe a bit more code would be interesting. What is this #balance object ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/

Comment: @RomainBraun balance is a div element

Comment: @Steve Yeah, I kind of guessed that... I meant I'd like to see your HTML code as well. Your table if you wish.

Comment: @RomainBraun its about 2k rows of code which part you want to see?

Comment: @Steve The table part. Where the #balance object is declared. If it's too long just upload it to pastebin.

Comment: @RomainBraun: in a nut shell: http://pastebin.com/QtTxXnzX

Answer (score 0):

> ...but on second ajax call on click event of odd row (shows
>   and hides next row) on third call (show, hide, show) after forth
>   call(show, hide, show,hide) and it goes on and on increases with every
>   ajax calls.

this is because your `$('#balance').on("click", "table", ...)` event handler is within the `dropBoxChanged` function and therefore called each time the drop down box changes.  [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is intended for what you're using it for but it only needs to be called once.  Your `balance` div remains on the page between ajax calls so each click on that element will be handled by the `.on()` event handler.

so to fix it move the `.on()` code block outside of the `dropBoxChanged` function and it will work correctly (do make sure it's within a `$(document).ready(...)` function).

Also, you had `.slideUp` to show the even rows however [animations aren't supported on table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row).  [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) should get you what you need instead of `.slideUp`.

> Also I don't know how to initially hide even rows.

Two ways you could hide the even rows:

1. I'd recommend setting the even rows server-side to a class that is already set to hide like `class="hide"` (or the less favored inline option `style="display:none"`)
2. Use jQuery in your ajax callback function, after you set your `balance` div content then call something like

```
$('#balance > table tr:nth-child(even)').hide();
```

Comment: I moved it outside within $(document).ready(...) with no success. It needs to be inside dropBoxChanged function because when document is ready the ajax table isn't loaded yet.

Comment: I solved the problem with a dirty trick by removing and adding div element inside dropBoxChanged function. So every time it ads #balance element again and then sets  event handler to it.Thanks your answer helped me alot

Comment: Now I'm initially hiding even rows but problem is after initial hide it  sliding is not working at all and they remaining hidden.

Comment: @Steve you may want to use `.toggle` instead of `.slideUp`, table rows aren't supported in jQuery animations.