# Jquery animate not working. I need to add a row to table with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that adds a row to a table the row id="dummy" I need it to animate this. I need the other rows to slide down.

I have to the following code but it doesnt animate just adds the row.

```
var removeImage = '<td><img src="images/b_redcross.gif" alt="" hspace=0 border="0" align="absMiddle" style="cursor:pointer;width:1.2em;width:1.2em; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;" ></td>';
        var html = '<tr><td class="blueFont_inset">test</td><td class="blueFont_inset">test</td>'+removeStaffImage+"</tr></td>";
        $(html).hide().insertAfter($("#dummy")).slideDown('slow');
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Your code works fine, you should make a fiddle to show your specific case so we can have a look at it. This fiddle shows the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/Kennethtruyers/utXCc/

Answer (score 1):

This is addressed in the following question:

[How to Use slideDown (or show) function on a table row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row)

Basically you need to wrap the content of the td in a div and animate that.