# expand/collapse table rows with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to expand and collapse table rows when header columns is clicked. I only want to expand/collapse rows which are under the specific header (clicked).

Here is my table structure:

```html
 <table border="0">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Header</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Header</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>date</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Any thoughts on how can I accomplish this task. Using div this task seems quite simple, but I have tabular data which I want to manipulate.

One idea I can think of is to use css class in every row which distinguish rows in under each header and use JQuery to expand/collapse those rows only when header is clicked. But if my table has 10-15 headers then it seems difficult to keep track of css classes.

Please suggest a suitable way to achieve this.

Comment: I'd suggest you use nested lists (`ul`, `ol` or even `dl`) rather than `table` elements for this.

Comment: If you're using header cells why aren't you also using `<th>`?

Comment: yeah, I can use <th> but what purpose will it serve?

Comment: Well first of all semantics, second it's a little easier to target with selector syntax.

Comment: @DavidThomas the application, I am working with, already have table structure in place and is being used everywhere. I am kind of bound to use table structure. Btw, is it possible if I can use multiple `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags to structure the table. I think this can help?

Comment: While you can have multiple `tbody` elements I'm pretty certain that you can only have *one* `thead` element, so I'm not sure that would help. I have, though, posted an answer which I *think* meets your needs. Though it does involve adding a class-name to the `tr` elements that contain a header.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can try this way:-

Give a class say `header` to the header rows, use nextUntil to get all rows beneath the clicked header until the next header.

#### JS

```
$('.header').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

#### Html

```
<table border="0">
  <tr  class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ty3b/)

Another Example:

```
$('.header').click(function(){
   $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value){return value=='-'?'+':'-'});
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100); // or just use "toggle()"
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y4Mdy/)

You can also use promise to toggle the span icon/text after the toggle is complete in-case of animated toggle.

```
$('.header').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100).promise().done(function () {
        $this.find('span').text(function (_, value) {
            return value == '-' ? '+' : '-'
        });
    });
});
```

[.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

[.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Or just with a css pseudo element to represent the sign of expansion/collapse, and just toggle a class on the header.

CSS:-

```
.header .sign:after{
  content:"+";
  display:inline-block;      
}
.header.expand .sign:after{
  content:"-";
}
```

JS:-

```
$(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100);
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nc8bt9ss/)

Comment: Just curious, but why not use the cached `$this` in the very next line?

Comment: am getting this error : Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'nextUntil'

Comment: Just to complement, `.toggle()` works better than `.slideToggle(100);` when there are many lines to toggle.

Comment: This didn't work if the header row was inside a <thead> tag. Also if the header rows have controls like dropdownlists for filtering, this will also toggle on/off even when the user only want to interact with the control.

Comment: This isn't super important, but if for some reason you couldn't add a class to the `td`, jQuery could still select the headers with `$('td[colspan="2"]').parent()`

Comment: Great Answer, very descriptive. Didnt knew i could do that in one & half lines.

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way to achieve this, without changing the HTML `table`-based structure, is to use a class-name on the `tr` elements containing a header, such as `.header`, to give:

```
<table border="0">
  <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the jQuery:

```
// bind a click-handler to the 'tr' elements with the 'header' class-name:
$('tr.header').click(function(){
    /* get all the subsequent 'tr' elements until the next 'tr.header',
       set the 'display' property to 'none' (if they're visible), to 'table-row'
       if they're not: */
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').css('display', function(i,v){
        return this.style.display === 'table-row' ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zFJwa/).

In the linked demo I've used CSS to hide the `tr` elements that *don't* have the `header` class-name; in practice though (despite the relative rarity of users with JavaScript disabled) I'd suggest using JavaScript to add the relevant class-names, hiding and showing as appropriate:

```
// hide all 'tr' elements, then filter them to find...
$('tr').hide().filter(function () {
    // only those 'tr' elements that have 'td' elements with a 'colspan' attribute:
    return $(this).find('td[colspan]').length;
    // add the 'header' class to those found 'tr' elements
}).addClass('header')
    // set the display of those elements to 'table-row':
  .css('display', 'table-row')
    // bind the click-handler (as above)
  .click(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').css('display', function (i, v) {
        return this.style.display === 'table-row' ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zFJwa/1/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).

Answer (score 8):

I liked the simplest answer provided. However, I didn't like the choppiness of the collapsing. So I combined a solution from this question: [How to Use slideDown (or show) function on a table row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row)
to make it a smoother animation when the rows slide up or down. It involves having to wrap the content of each td in a div. This allows it to smoothly animate the collapsing. When the rows are expanded, it will replace the div, with just the content.

So here's the html:

```
<table>
<tr class="header">
    <td>CARS</td>
</tr>
<tr class="thing">
    <td>car</td>
</tr>
<tr class="thing">
    <td>truck</td>
</tr>
<tr class="header">
    <td>HOUSES</td>
</tr>
<tr class="thing">
    <td>split level</td>
</tr>
<tr class="thing">
    <td>trailer</td>
</tr>
```

And here's the js

```
$('.header').click(function(){
if($(this).hasClass("collapsed")){
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header')
    .find('td')
    .parent()
    .find('td > div')
    .slideDown("fast", function(){
        var $set = $(this);
        $set.replaceWith($set.contents());
    });
    $(this).removeClass("collapsed");
} else {
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header')
    .find('td')
    .wrapInner('<div style="display: block;" />')
    .parent()
    .find('td > div')
    .slideUp("fast");
    $(this).addClass("collapsed");
}
});
```

Checkout this fiddle for an example
https://jsfiddle.net/p9mtqhm7/52/

Answer (score 8):

I expanded one of the answers, however my functionality is a bit different. In my version, different rows form different groups. And "header" row triggers collapsing/expanding of that particular group. Also, each individual subgroup memorizes state that its in. It might sound a bit confusing, you can test drive my version using jsfiddle. Hope this code snippets will be helpful to someone out there!

**HTML**

```
<table border="0">
  <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='group1'>Group 1</td>
    <td>data 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group1'>
    <td>data 3</td>
    <td>data 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='group2'>Group 2</td>
    <td>data 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group2'>
    <td>data 3</td>
    <td>data 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group2'>
    <td class='sub_group1'>Sub Group 1</td>
    <td>data 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group2 sub_group1'>
    <td>data 7</td>
    <td>data 8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group2 sub_group1'>
    <td>data 9</td>
    <td>data 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group2 sub_group1'>
    <td class='sub_sub_group1'>Sub Sub Group 1</td>
    <td>data 11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group2 sub_group1 sub_sub_group1'>
    <td>data 12</td>
    <td>data 13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group2 sub_group1 sub_sub_group1'>
    <td>data 14</td>
    <td>data 15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group2'>
    <td class='sub_group2'>Sub Group 2</td>
    <td>data 11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group2 sub_group2'>
    <td>data 12</td>
    <td>data 13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group2 sub_group2'>
    <td>data 14</td>
    <td>data 15</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table, tr, td, th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

img.button_open{
  content:url('http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/collapsible-lists/button-open.png');
  cursor:pointer;
}

img.button_closed{
  content: url('http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/collapsible-lists/button-closed.png');
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
function CreateGroup(group_name)
{
    // Create Button(Image)
    $('td.' + group_name).prepend("<img class='" + group_name + " button_closed'> ");
    // Add Padding to Data
    $('tr.' + group_name).each(function () {
        var first_td = $(this).children('td').first();
        var padding_left = parseInt($(first_td).css('padding-left'));
        $(first_td).css('padding-left', String(padding_left + 25) + 'px');
    });
    RestoreGroup(group_name);

    // Tie toggle function to the button
    $('img.' + group_name).click(function(){
        ToggleGroup(group_name);
    });
}

function ToggleGroup(group_name)
{
    ToggleButton($('img.' + group_name));
    RestoreGroup(group_name);
}

function RestoreGroup(group_name)
{
    if ($('img.' + group_name).hasClass('button_open'))
    {
        // Open everything
        $('tr.' + group_name).show();

        // Close subgroups that been closed
        $('tr.' + group_name).find('img.button_closed').each(function () {
            sub_group_name = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/)[0];
            //console.log(sub_group_name);
            RestoreGroup(sub_group_name);
        });
    }

    if ($('img.' + group_name).hasClass('button_closed'))
    {
        // Close everything
        $('tr.' + group_name).hide();
    }
}

function ToggleButton(button)
{
    $(button).toggleClass('button_open');
    $(button).toggleClass('button_closed');
}

CreateGroup('group1');
CreateGroup('group2');
CreateGroup('sub_group1');
CreateGroup('sub_group2');
CreateGroup('sub_sub_group1');
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/y4Mdy/1372/)**

Comment: Very nice result, thank you. It will become better when [wai-aria](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/) will be used to make it more accessible.

Answer (score 5):

I would say using the `data-` attribute to match the headers with the elements inside it. Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GbRAZ/1/

A preview of the HTML alteration :

```
   <tr class="header" id="header1">
    <td colspan="2">Header</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-for="header1" style="display:none">
     <td>data</td>
     <td>data</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-for="header1" style="display:none">
     <td>data</td>
     <td>data</td>
   </tr>
```

JS code :

```
$(".header").click(function () {
   $("[data-for="+this.id+"]").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

**EDIT**:
But, it involves some HTML changes. so I dunno if thats what you wanted. A better way to structure this would be using `<th>` or by changing the entire html to use `ul, ol, etc` or even a `div > span` setup.

Answer (score 0):

[A JavaScript accordion](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) does the trick.

[This fiddle by W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion) makes a simple task even more simple using nothing but javascript, which i partially reproduce below.

```
<head>
<style>
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd; 
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
}

div.panel.show {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head><body>
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
</script>
...
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
...
<button class="accordion">Table</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p><table name="detail_table">...</table></p>
</div>
...
<button class="accordion"><table name="button_table">...</table></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <table name="detail_table">...</table>
  <img src=...></img>
</div>
...
</body></html>
```

if using php, don't forget to convert `"` to `'`.  You can also use tables of data inside the button and it will still work.

Answer (score -3):

using jQuery it's easy...

```
 $('YOUR CLASS SELECTOR').click(function(){

            $(this).toggle();
});
```