# Expand and Collapse Using XSLT

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

The XML file is

```
<TG>
    <RunId>
    <Id>
    <TgTitle>
    <TC>
        <RunId>
        <id>
        <TcTitle>
        <TCI>
            <Id>
            <Title>
            <Description>
            <Status>
        <TCI>
        <TCI>
            <Id>
            <Title>
            <Description>
            <Status>
        <TCI>
        <TCI>
            <Id>
            <Title>
            <Description>
            <Status>
        <TCI>
    </TC>
    <TC>
        <RunId>
        <id>
        <TcTitle>
        <TCI>
            <Id>    
            <Title>
            <Description>
            <Status>
        <TCI>
        <TCI>
            <Id>
            <Title>
            <Description>
            <Status>
        <TCI>
    </TC>
</TG>
```

I have created an XSLT that would list like this (used HTML table)

```
TG Summary 
TG RunId: 
TG Id
TG Title

- TC Summary 
TC Run Id 
TC Id
TC Title 
TCIId TCI Title Description             Status 
1      Title 1      instruction 1       Pass
2      Title 2      instruction 2       Pass
3      Title 3      instruction 3       Pass

- TC Summary 
TC Run Id 
TC Id
TC Title 
TCIId TCI Title Description             Status 
1      Title 1      instruction 1       Pass
2      Title 2      instruction 2       Pass
```

When i Initially open this the xml file 
The Tree should be collapsed mode, When user clicks  "+" on the TC summary row should the details be expanded, and the "+" should change to "-" and vice versa 
I tried couple of options but that did not work. Can any one help. 
New to Javascript/HTML/XSLT

Comment: These are two questions with independent audience.
1. Find a javascript way to do it
2. Find an xslt way to generate the html/javascript as needed for 1.

Comment: An XSLt way to generate the Html/javascript is required

Comment: Well, for that you have first to specify the exact html/javascript way. You can only generate it if you know what to generate.

Comment: use search: [expand collapse table rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926752/expand-collapse-table-rows-with-jquery). there are many ways to get to a solution. search the web based on your given environment, like what js-libary can you use and so on.