# Collapse HTML table rows by default

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using slight modification from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16926867/7954504) answer to make header rows collapsible in an HTML table.

**I want to modify the JS snippet so that rows are collapsed rather than expanded by default (on page load/document ready).** How can I do this?

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is for:

```
$(this).find('span').text(function(_, value){return value=='-'?'+':'-'});
$(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100, function(){
```

to be run once at page load/refresh, in addition to when header rows are clicked and toggled.

I know that I'll need to change the two tags two `<span>+</span>` in HTML, but am stuck on how to trigger this behavior on page load.

---

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr.header').click(function(){
        $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value){return value=='-'?'+':'-'});
        $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100, function(){
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table border="0">
  <tr  class="header">
      <th colspan="2">Header <span>-</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr  class="header">
    <th colspan="2">Header <span>-</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table, tr, td, th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
tr.header
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mkb39x0u/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you'd just do this in document.ready:

```
$('tr:not(.header)').hide();
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hrg4d5oj/5/)**

Also, I'd probably toggle visibility of your plus and minus characters with a class on the row and CSS rather than cluttering up your script with that.

Answer (score 3):

I just update your code with few **JS changes**, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

**Add below JS code before your click method**

```
$('tr.header').nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr.header').nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100);
    $('tr.header').click(function(){
        $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value){return value=='-'?'+':'-'});
        $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100, function(){
        });
    });
});
```

```css
table, tr, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
tr.header {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0">
  <tr  class="header">
      <th colspan="2">Header <span>-</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr  class="header">
    <th colspan="2">Header <span>-</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Another way you can achieve this functionality by using CSS**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr.header').click(function(){
        $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value){return value=='-'?'+':'-'});
        $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100, function(){
        });
    });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: none;
}

td + td {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

tr + tr {
  border-top: 0;
}

tr.header {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0">
  <tr  class="header">
      <th colspan="2">Header <span>-</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr  class="header">
    <th colspan="2">Header <span>-</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```