# How to expand/collapse entire HTML table after clicking a certain object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, expand

I have an html script like below:

```
...
<h2>Invoice Registers</h2>
<table id="mytable" border="1"> 
   <tr>
      <th>Control Number</th><th>Payee Name</th>
      <th>Workflow Step</th><th>Date Created</th>  
   </tr>
   <tr>...my data...</tr>
   <tr>...my data...</tr>
   <tr>...my data...</tr>
</table>
...
```

What I want is to expand or collapse the **entire HTML table** when I click on "Invoice Registers" text.
If I had the `<h2>` inside the table, I'd use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926752/expand-collapse-table-rows-with-jquery) and manage this, but couldn't find a solution for the current situation. How can I handle this? Note that the `<h2>` tag must stay out of the table. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the next `table` after this `h2`, and toggle it?

```js
$('h2').click(function () {
  $(this).nextAll('table').eq(0).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Invoice Registers</h2>
<table border="1"> 
   <tr>
      <th>Control Number</th><th>Payee Name</th>
      <th>Workflow Step</th><th>Date Created</th>  
   </tr>
</table>

<h2>Something else</h2>
<table border="1"> 
   <tr>
      <th>Control Number</th><th>Payee Name</th>
      <th>Workflow Step</th><th>Date Created</th>  
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Bonus**

If you want an animation, wrap your tables in a `div` *(`table` elements cannot be animated)*:

```js
$('h2').click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('.table-wrapper').eq(0).slideToggle(400);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Invoice Registers</h2>
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Control Number</th><th>Payee Name</th>
      <th>Workflow Step</th><th>Date Created</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<h2>Something else</h2>
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Control Number</th><th>Payee Name</th>
      <th>Workflow Step</th><th>Date Created</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't this just be `$(this).next('table').toggle();` instead of nextAll?

Comment: It would work in the specific HTML example he provided, because `next` returns either the next element or `undefined` if it does not match the selector. However, to be more future-proof in case he adds stuff between the `h2` and the `table`, I used `nextAll` which will still work in that case

Answer (score 2):

you need to use javascript to do the actual work. You also need something in a "a" tag or button to trigger the javascript. Should be something like this. I haven't tested this btw.

```
<h2>Invoice Registers</h2>
<table id="mytable" border="1"> 
   <tr>
      <th>Control Number</th><th>Payee Name</th>
      <th>Workflow Step</th><th>Date Created</th>  
   </tr>
   <tr>...my data...</tr>
   <tr>...my data...</tr>
   <tr>...my data...</tr>
</table>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Hide/Unhide</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mytable");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a click handler to the `<h2>` which toggles the display of the table. Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ob8p52n6/

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an animated expand/collapse type thing, you'll need something more complex, but if you just want to show/hide it, try this:

```js
function showTable(tableName) {
  const tbl = document.getElementById(tableName);
  tbl.style.display = tbl.style.display === 'none' ? 
    'block' : 'none';
}
```

```css
#mytable {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2 onclick="showTable('mytable')">Invoice Registers</h2>
<table id="mytable" border="1"> 
   <tr>
      <th>Control Number</th><th>Payee Name</th>
      <th>Workflow Step</th><th>Date Created</th>  
   </tr>
   <tr>...my data...</tr>
   <tr>...my data...</tr>
   <tr>...my data...</tr>
</table>
```