# `event.dataTransfer` working only on `drop` but not on `dragover`

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a continuation to my failed [attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75935047/how-to-make-a-draggable-list-change-place-before-mouse-release) to enable smooth transition during list element switching. Since I haven't found any good solutions yet, I'm considering to switch elements on `dragover` instead of `drop`. However, when I use `e.dataTransfer`, it works only for `drop` and not `dragover`:

```js
function dragStart(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', $(e.target).index());
    console.log('dragstart', e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
}

function sortableDropped(e) {
    console.log('drop', e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
}

function preventDefault(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}

function dragOver(e) {
    preventDefault(e);
    console.log('dragover', e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
}

function onLoad() {
    for (let item of document.querySelectorAll('.sortable-item')) {
        item.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
        item.addEventListener('drop', sortableDropped);
        item.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
    }
}

onLoad();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #000000;
}
.sortable-item {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 12px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: grab;
    border: 1px solid #5c636a;
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: #ffffff;
}


.sortable-item:active {
    border: 1px solid #0d6efd;
    cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul class="sortable-list list-unstyled">
    <li class="sortable-item" draggable="true">
        A
    </li>
    <li class="sortable-item" draggable="true">
        B
    </li>
    <li class="sortable-item" draggable="true">
        C
    </li>
    <li class="sortable-item" draggable="true">
        D
    </li>
</ul>
```

But clearly something is not working as expected, this is what I get in the console when the first `li` element is dragged over another:

```
dragstart 0
744 dragover 
drop 0
```

I'm expecting `744 dragover 0`.

Answer (score 0):

`dragOver` does not have access to the data transfer object, only drop does.
you could assign it to a shared variable on start, if that helps.

```
let sharedVariable = null;

function dragStart(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', $(e.target).index());
    sharedVariable = $(e.target).index();
}

function sortableDropped(e) {
    console.log('drop', e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
}

function preventDefault(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}

function dragOver(e) {
    preventDefault(e);
    console.log('dragover', sharedVariable);
}

function onLoad() {
    for (let item of document.querySelectorAll('.sortable-item')) {
        item.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
        item.addEventListener('drop', sortableDropped);
        item.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
    }
}

onLoad();
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the shared variable part?

Comment: does that work for you?

Comment: no, I don't like the global variable approach

Comment: why is it a global variable tho? for one, i am using let and then, you are not forced to put that in the global scope, you could jsut make an anonymous call or even use addEventListener. and clearly, it solves your issue of not having the value at hand at the events inception.