# How to hide the after drag (returning back to place) effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is a list of draggable items, I want to eliminate the drag after effect which looks like the list item is going back to where it was dragged from, which happens whenever the mouse is released.

[image: effect]

```js
function listItemDragged(e) {
    e.target.classList.add('dragging');
    let dropTarget =
        document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY) === null
            ? e.target
            : document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);

    if (e.target.parentNode === dropTarget.parentNode) {
        dropTarget =
            dropTarget !== e.target.nextSibling
                ? dropTarget
                : dropTarget.nextSibling;
        e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(e.target, dropTarget);
    }
}

function listItemDropped(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('dragging');
}

function onLoad() {
    let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
    Array.prototype.map.call(listItems, (option) => {
        option.ondrag = listItemDragged;
        option.ondragend = listItemDropped;
    });
}
onLoad();
```

```css
 

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
}

body {
    background-color: #2b3035;
}

.draggable {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #5c636a;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #212529;
    cursor: grab;
    color: #ffffff;
    touch-action: none
}

.dragging {
    cursor: grabbing;
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
 
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class='sortable-list list-unstyled'>
<li class='draggable' draggable='true'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1
</li>
<li class='draggable' draggable='true'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2
</li>
<li class='draggable' draggable='true'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3
</li>
<li class='draggable' draggable='true'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 4
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce using your snippet on Chrome 111. What was the environment you tested this on?

Comment: Chrome Version 112.0.5615.49 (Official Build) (x86_64) on macOS Monterey 12.6.4

Comment: Updated to 112.0.5615.50, still fail to reproduce. I'm on Windows, though.

Comment: Works as intended on Brave and firefox as well (Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the browser's default dragover action using the following code:

```
document.querySelector('.sortable-list').addEventListener("dragover", cancelDefault);
```

Here is a complete sample code demonstrating how to create a sortable list with drag and drop functionality:

```js
function listItemDragged(e) {
  e.target.classList.add("dragging");
  let dropTarget =
    document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY) === null
      ? e.target
      : document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);

  if (e.target.parentNode === dropTarget.parentNode) {
    dropTarget =
      dropTarget !== e.target.nextSibling ? dropTarget : dropTarget.nextSibling;
    e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(e.target, dropTarget);
  }
}

function listItemDropped(e) {
  e.target.classList.remove("dragging");
  e.preventDefault();
}

function onLoad() {
  let listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");
  Array.prototype.map.call(listItems, (option) => {
    option.ondrag = listItemDragged;
    option.ondragend = listItemDropped;
  });
  document.querySelector('.sortable-list').addEventListener("dragover", (e) => e.preventDefault());
}

onLoad();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
}

body {
    background-color: #2b3035;
}

.draggable {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #5c636a;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #212529;
    cursor: grab;
    color: #ffffff;
    touch-action: none
}

.dragging {
    cursor: grabbing;
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class='sortable-list list-unstyled'>
  <li class='draggable' draggable='true'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1
  </li>
  <li class='draggable' draggable='true'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2
  </li>
  <li class='draggable' draggable='true'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3
  </li>
  <li class='draggable' draggable='true'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 4
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: any idea how to animate the reordering to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnlrW.gif)?

Comment: You can apply an animation class before using the `insertBefore` method to achieve the desired effect."

Comment: which animation class should I use in this case, to be able to control the swap delay? I tried `$(e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(e.target, beforeTarget)).animate()`, not sure if this is the proper way, it's not working anyway.

Comment: @nlblack323 Based on the new information you provided, it seems that your question may require another solution. It might be a good idea to post a new question with the updated information to get more targeted answers from the community. Please let me know if you need any help or guidance with this.

Comment: I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75935047/how-to-make-a-draggable-list-change-place-before-mouse-release) a few days ago, dedicated for that purpose which got no answers yet. I will update it with the new changes so you can check it out.