# slideToggle expands too far/jumps back

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

If you click the SERVICES link under the logo the menu will expand a little too far and then in one quick flash, it cuts back to the desired height. Any way to cure this bug?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li#service-toggle-link").click(function () {
    $(".toggle-content").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: Must be browser specific, cause it works like a charm in Chrome ?

Comment: Weird, it doesn't seem to work at all for me in Chrome or Safari

Comment: The LI elements are wider than the menu, so the border sticks out on the right side, but there is no jumping when the menu slides down. Did you hit CTRL-F5 to clear the cache etc ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by that, it doesn't appear to be an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<nav id="site-navigation">` seems to have an unnecessary `display: table`. Try removing it and everything should work fine.

Tables are not meant to be animated with jQuery, you can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/920480/1446845

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in FF when you set the height of div.toggle-content (for example for 176px)

I dunno why, maybe FF has some issues with autoheight