# Animate table with jquery (if possible)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have code that shows dynamically created tables of varying lengths, with 'expand' and 'condense' buttons that show/hide extra table rows.  It works but it's ugly.  I'd love to animate it but apparently that's not possible.  This is probably a duplicate of [How to Use slideDown (or show) function on a table row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row), in which case feel free to close it, but that was four years old and I was hoping there might be a new/better solution (I couldn't get those to work, but I can keep trying).  If animating is not an option, maybe someone can suggest some other design feature that might look decent?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.table').each(function(){
        $(this).find("tr:even").addClass("even");
        $(this).find("tr:odd").addClass("odd");
        var numShown = 2; // Initial rows shown & index

        var $table = $(this).find('tbody');  // tbody containing all the rows
        var numRows = $table.find('tr').length; // Total # rows
        var tableWidth = $table.find('tr:first td').length;
        var expandDiv = '<tbody class="more"><tr><td colspan="' +
                           tableWidth + '"><div>Show More</div</tbody></td></tr>';
        var condenseDiv = '<tbody class="less"><tr><td colspan="' + $table.find('tr:first td').length + '"><div>Show Less</div</tbody></td></tr>';
        if(numRows>numShown){
            $(function () {
                // Hide rows and add clickable div
                $table.find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end()
                    .after(expandDiv);

            })          
        };
        $(this).on('click', '.more', (function() {
            // numShown = numShown + numMore;
            $(this).remove();
            $table.find('tr').show();   
            $table.after(condenseDiv);
        }));
        $(this).on('click', '.less', (function() {
            $table.find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end()
                .after(expandDiv);
            $(this).remove();    
        })
        )

    });
});
```

Comment: Looks like wrapping the table in a div and .animate() or .slide** on that worked for some people.

Comment: Yeah, I had trouble understanding/implementing it (very new to this) so I wanted to see if there maybe was a more up-to-date solution before I invested too much time into it.  I'll keep trying.

Comment: Yeah I would say try to make a jsfiddle and see if it works.  I like to have a little more control over my animations, so I would use jquery .animate().  You can start it with 0 height and go to 100px or whatever you want to do, it's a little finer control of the css.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to collapse certain parts of a table, but I did something like this before:

```
   <div onclick="$('#myTable').toggle(300)">
      Name of table here
      <div id="myTable">
        <table>
          <tr><td>I am a cell</td></tr>
          <tr><td>I am another cell</td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This creates a div where clicking on the title expands/collapses the table. Is this close to what you're looking for?

Comment: Not exactly--I have it set so that it only displays the first few rows until you click 'Show more' (and then 'show less' to hide them).  It works, but I'd like to animate it with a slide to prettify it.