# Rails jQuery UI show('blind', 1000) is not working properly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on Ruby on rails guides from the book Agile web development with Rails 4.
There is a task to jQueryUI method show with blind effect. The problem here is that my cart will appear as expected, but the effect will not work properly. When ever I will add something to my cart, the targeted div will eventually appear, but in a weird way: at first some empty space will pop-up in its place, and after 1 sec the whole div with its' content will appear.

I tried to use hide('blind', 1000) on the same div, but the only thing I am getting, div instantly disappears.

`jquery-ui-rails gem is installed`

`//= require jquery.ui.effect-blind` is set in application.js

```
if ($('#cart tr').length == 1) { $('#cart').show('blind', 1000); }
```

Maybe some one knows how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing anything in action.  Any chance you can post a JSBin that illustrates the problem?

Comment: you can see how it works [here](http://hidden-bastion-4143.herokuapp.com/) just add some products, or remove all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animations are not supported on table rows.  See this answer for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/a/920480/631187

Comment: Thank you for the reference, now I see where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using "show" instead of "blind". I set `.lenght > -1` cause it didn't shown properly after adding the first product.

```
if ($('#cart tr').length > -1){
  $('#cart').show('show', 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a fix, what you need to do is move some css around.

just put,

```
form, div{
    display: inline;
}
```

under the cart definition in the application.css.scss file.