# How to animate table rows while prepending to existing table

Tags: jquery, twitter, html-table, jquery-animate, prepend

I'm prepending the name, tweet and timestamp as a row into an existing HTML table. I'm using codebird-js to get the tweets. My existing code simply prepends the new tweets into the table. But I want to add a slow slidedown animation to the new table rows when they get prepended at the top. The aim is to give an impression to the viewer that the existing rows are pushed down to make room for the new rows. So far been unable to do that. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the HTML

```
<input type="text" id="tweet-form" placeholder="search text...">
<button id="tweet-button" onclick="showTweets();">Get Tweets</button>

<div id="tweet-rows">
    <table></table>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#tweet-rows {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function showTweets() {
    var tweetText = $('#tweet-form').val();
    console.log(tweetText);

    var cb = new Codebird;
    cb.setConsumerKey(
           "CONSUMER_KEY", 
           "CONSUMER_SECRET"
    );

    cb.setToken(
            "ACCESS_TOKEN", 
            "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"
    );

    cb.__call(
        "search_tweets", {
         q : tweetText,
         },
     function (reply) {

       for(var i=reply.statuses.length-1; i>=0; i--) {

         var name = reply.statuses[i].user.name;
         var tweet = reply.statuses[i].text;
         var timestamp = reply.statuses[i].created_at;

         $('#tweet-rows > table').prepend('<tr><td>@' + name + '</td><td>' + tweet + '</td><td>' + timestamp + '</td></tr>');

        //console.log('@' + name + ' : ' + tweet + ' ' + timestamp);

        }

       $('#tweet-rows').show();  

     }, true
    );
}
```

I've cooked up this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saifwilljones/UQUEU/1/) where I've tried to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make a table-row animate unfortunately.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/920480/2702894

Is there any reason for using a table rather than divs?

It is achievable through some 'trickery' but involves:

creating a new table with the content you want to add on one row

adding that table the same number of pixels up as the size of a table row

animating that table down and your existing table at the same speed and time

then at last second removing the new temporary table and prepending the row to your existing table.

Also this still won't give you a fade effect.

As you can see - tricky - divs would be better :-P

Comment: Any fiddle for that use case? I am trying to do something very similar, basically I have it all working except move the existing divs down gracefully.

Comment: Hi Dan, best thing to do is create a fiddle and post it as a new question - I will keep an eye out for it. If you are using divs and jQuery though you just prepend the div to the container with `.slideDown(500)` say (so `$('#container').prepend('Row HTML IN HERE').hide().slideDown(500);` would work.

Comment: here is a new fiddle thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722774/elegantly-animate-a-stack-of-divs

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand how you want that animation, so I just edited your fiddle a little bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/UQUEU/17/

The effect is done by this piece of code:

```
$(row).fadeIn("slow");
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: If you want a slide down animation, this is impossible with table-rows like Graham Ritchie says, use divs if you want it.

Comment: I don't want the fade in animation. In effect, I want to reduce the speed of the existing rows moving down when the new row takes the top spot. Anyway, I'll try the animation with divs. Can you give some code example on using divs for this particular case?