# elegantly animate a stack of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to achieve a nice animation, however I am a bit stuck using CSS only to achieve the effect that I want. Currently I am using animate.css to animate new elements in, but the old element dont move gracefully, since I have no further animation.

Here is a http://jsfiddle.net/tcq8kuy6/1/ illustrating the current state of my animation.

```
setInterval(function(){
    var newbox = "<div class='child animated bounceInDown'></div>"
$('.container').prepend(newbox);

}, 2000);
```

Comment: Why don't you animate your stack of child elements down a bit before a new element is added using CSS3 translateY() since the height of these individual child elements is known

Comment: well in that case its known, but the divs can have different sizes. I could not find a way to simply say slide down 100px before insert that is what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcq8kuy6/5/)

In order to make this work I did a couple of things:-

1 CSS

```
 .child {
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 display: block; //inline block results in jerkiness when inserting items 
 margin:2px; //added margin to compensate for inline-block becoming block.
 border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
 }
```

2 JS

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var newbox = "<div class='child  animated bounceInDown'></div>"
    $(newbox).prependTo('.container').hide().slideDown(500);//notice that I prepend to the container, then hide the 'newbox' and then slide it down -> this gives the desired effect.

}, 2000);
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Hi Graham thanks for the fiddle, can you explain to me what does the hide function do?

Comment: When you prepend the div it is visible and so has a height of 40px - this would make the existing items jerk downwards - so `.hide()` does just that - it hides the div you are inserting (think of .hide as setting CSS display:none), without it you will experience all the existing divs dropping down quickly then going back up in certain browsers.