# Add table row with animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to add a table row on-the-fly, I want to make it animated. The problem is this code do not animate table height, it gets longer instantly, but I want to make it smoothly, like `fadeIn()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mfrmAdd").on("click", function () {
            var _tr;
            _tr = "<tr id='foo1'>" +
            "<td>col1</td>" +
            "<td>col2</td>" +
            "</tr>";
            $(_tr).hide().insertAfter("#startPoint").fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

You can view the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/utXC2/

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row

Comment: jQuery is version 1.10.x, that topic is about v1.1