# Adding a row to jquery-datatable using slideDown()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In my view, I have two divs, one responsible for adding an entry to my database, and one responsible for showing all of my database table rows when the page loads.  The div responsible for displaying the contents of my table uses the Datatables jQuery plugin, which makes my life easier as far as displaying this content goes.

Both of these divs work just fine, separately.  However, I would like to integrate them together such that when I add an entry using my first div, the database is updated, and this entry is then appended to my Datatable in my second div, without reloading the entire page.

I'm aware that this process alone is easy enough using the Datatables API, simply by using the row.add() and draw() functions, this can be done, and is demonstrated [here](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html).

While this is a potential solution, I'm not completely satisfied with it, because the rest of my page utilizes jQuery's slideDown() for neat-looking animations, and I was hoping that I could apply this animation to adding another row to my Datatable.  If you look at their example, it simply inserts the row, but it would look better if I could make that row slide down from the table.

Is this something that could be done without spending too much time on it?  Or should I just stick with using the Datatables API and give up on trying to animate it?  I've already tried using jQuery to append a new row manually, but it looks terrible because I don't think I can reload the plugin to adopt the change into the Datatable.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Comment: Please Include Your code in question, rather including a link.

Comment: @VedantTerkar I'm asking for a method to modify or override the Datatables API, I don't think the code that I have for my two divs is relevant.  Plus, it's pretty lengthy.

Comment: slideDown is not supported on tr [http://stackoverflow.com/a/920480/2359055](http://stackoverflow.com/a/920480/2359055)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I've solved It!

[**## `DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/fmLAR/2/)

I've observed When click on `#addRow` button takes place, It adds a `<tr>` with class `.odd` or `.even` 
Depending on the number of that `row` ie, `1,3,5...` are odd `2,4,6...` are even.

So I've added CSS to make smooth transitions for height of `tr`, setting height of `td` ultimately will affect the height of `tr`. So here is my CSS:

```
.odd td{
    height:0px;
    transition:all ease 1s;
    padding:5px;
}
.even td{
    height:0px;
    transition:all ease 1s;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Now When the `click` event on `#addRow` button occurs, We just need to animate the `last` `tr` to specific `height`, to achieve `slideDown` effect.

That row can be either `.odd` or `.even` depending on the `counter` variable which is incremented each time when `row` is added.

So that's what I Do in JQuery.

Here is My JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#example').DataTable();
    var counter = 1;

    $('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
        var tr=t.row;
        tr.add( [
            counter +'.1',
            counter +'.2',
            counter +'.3',
            counter +'.4',
            counter +'.5'
        ] ).draw();
        var cls= counter%2!=0 ? ".odd" : ".even"; //class of latest row added (odd or even) %2 will do it.
        $(cls).last().animate({
            "height":"50px"
        },1000); // Acheive slideDown();
        counter++; //Increment Counter Now.

    } );

    // Automatically add a first row of data
    $('#addRow').click();
});
```

This will serve you as a starting step.

Also Note that: `slideDown()` isn't supported on `<tr>`. Setting height manually using `css` to `0px` also fails. So I request you to use `fadeIn()` instead of changing height using `animate`.

Hope it helps. Cheers :)!

Comment: Woah, looks like you put a fair amount of work into this.  Nice job, that looks much better than what I was able to do.

Comment: Well Almost 2 hour. @MichaelParker, But I think it was nice to do it, learned new thing. I didn't know about this table plugin before. I'm glad that I could help you.