# jQuery slide animation for tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I implemented a function which is able to show/hide the content of a table row or column with a sliding animation.

**What the code does:**

1. Retrieve all cells of the column (`th`, `td`)
2. Wrap the content of each cell in a `<div class="wrapper" />`
3. Animate the `width` of the wrapper div with jQuery.animate();
4. After finishing, unwrap the cell contents (remove the div)

The reason why I need the wrapping div is because jQuery can't perform a slide animation on table cells directly - see [How to Use slideDown (or show) function on a table row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row)

See this **[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxPwbw?editors=001)** for the code and demonstration. I removed as much JS code as possible to demonstrate my problem. *(You can ignore the html and css, they don't contain relevant information)*

**Everything works perfectly for rows and columns, in except of one (two?) problems:**

- When a column is shrinked, the content eventually starts wrapping when there's not enough space left. When this happens, the cell height suddenly increases, resulting in an ugly jump.
- When a cell content doesn't need the whole space of it's cell, the show-animation for this content is faster, resulting in ugly output.

[image]

What I want to achive is a constantly changing width without affecting the layout. The other columns must not be affected.
Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You could nest your div in another div with overflow hidden:

```
.crop {
    overflow:hidden; 
    width:100px
}
.inner { 
    min-width:300px; 
    width:auto; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mikatalk/7xwLjp2e/

Comment: You're setting the width - when I start expanding the column, I don't know it's final width, so I can't set it. Without the width, wrapping it in another div has no effect: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYOoEo?editors=001

Comment: The width I am setting (300px) would be the max width of the layout.

Comment: In my case, the layout of the table might change while it is hidden - the content of each cell can be modified, and after everything is done, the column is animated in. Therefore I don't know the max width (it is unclear until the browser rendered everything - which only happens after the animation finished).

Comment: Maybe just set a min width at least