# jQuery - Get all items with a specific class, that are right after the clicked object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a table, where the first Element has the class **inhalt**

right after this `tr`, are more `tr` with class **table2**. See the HTML below.

```
    <div id="sh_details">
     <div class="sh_wasserzeichen"></div>
     <article>
       <dl id="sh_accordion">
         <dt id="sh_2016">Headline1</dt>
      <dd><table>

         <tr>
             <th>Überschrift1</th>
             <th>Überschrift2</th>
             <th>Überschrift3</th>
             <th>Überschrift3</th>
             <th>Überschrift3</th>
             <th>Überschrift3</th>
             <th>Überschrift3</th>
             <th>Überschrift3</th>
             <th>Überschrift3</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td class="inhalt">Inhalt1</td>
           <td>Inhalt2</td>
           <td>Inhalt3</td>
           <td>Inhalt2</td>
           <td>Inhalt3</td>
           <td>Inhalt2</td>
           <td>Inhalt3</td>
           <td>Inhalt2</td>
           <td>Inhalt2</td>
          </tr>

          <!--Untertabelle1-->
          <tr class="table2">
               <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="table2">
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>

          </tr>

          <tr class="table2">
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="inhalt">Inhalt4</td>
            <td>Inhalt5</td>
            <td>Inhalt6</td>
            <td>Inhalt5</td>
            <td>Inhalt6</td>
            <td>Inhalt5</td>
            <td>Inhalt6</td>
            <td>Inhalt5</td>
            <td>Inhalt6</td>

          </tr>
          <!--Untertabelle2-->
          <tr class="table2">
               <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="table2">
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>

          </tr>



       </table></dd>

         <dt id="sh_january">Headline2</dt>
         <dd>125153226262Test</dd>
       </dl>
     </article>
  </div>
```

What im trying to do:

When the user clicks the `td` Element with class **inhalt** the `tr` - elements should slideDown (**until it finds tr-element, which has no class**)

jQuery:

```
$(".inhalt").stop().click(function(){

   $(this).addClass('table2_active');
   $(this).parents().next('tr').each(function() {

        if( $(this).attr('class') === undefined) { return false;}
        else {

               $(this).slideDown(300); }


    });
});
```

This code just gives me the first tr, but not the other ones.

Please see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybm4mrko/2/) . Hope you guys get the problem. Thanks!

**PS: Also the "slideDown"-Animation is not smooth - any ideas why?**

//EDIT:

So basically my idea was to build a loop which goes through all tr elements **DIRECTLY AFTER THE CLICKED .inhalt ITEM** and check if they have class .table2, when yes, slide down, when no, break the loop.

Comment: Try with: `$(this).parent().parent().find(".table2")...` instead. Or just `$(".table2")...` if these `tr` are the only ones with this class in the page.

Comment: `$(this).attr('class')` will return `""` and not `undefined`

Comment: @Arg0n This slides ALL .table2 down, i just want the .table2-elements which are **directly after** the clicked .inhalt item


So basically my idea was to build a loop which goes through all tr elements **DIRECTLY AFTER THE CLICKED .inhalt ITEM** and check if they have class .table2, when yes, slide down, when no, break the loop.

Comment: I'd place the rows you want inside a `<tbody>` then, and select all inside that.

Comment: Thanks, works perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/ybm4mrko/5/)

HTML

```
<div id="sh_details">
  <div class="sh_wasserzeichen"></div>
  <article>
    <dl id="sh_accordion">
      <dt id="sh_2016">Headline1</dt>
      <dd>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Überschrift1</th>
          <th>Überschrift2</th>
          <th>Überschrift3</th>
          <th>Überschrift3</th>
          <th>Überschrift3</th>
          <th>Überschrift3</th>
          <th>Überschrift3</th>
          <th>Überschrift3</th>
          <th>Überschrift3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="inhalt">Inhalt1</td>
          <td>Inhalt2</td>
          <td>Inhalt3</td>
          <td>Inhalt2</td>
          <td>Inhalt3</td>
          <td>Inhalt2</td>
          <td>Inhalt3</td>
          <td>Inhalt2</td>
          <td>Inhalt2</td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
          <!--Untertabelle1-->
          <tr class="table2">
            <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
            <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
            <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
            <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
            <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
            <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
            <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
            <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
            <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="table2">
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="table2">
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="inhalt">Inhalt4</td>
          <td>Inhalt5</td>
          <td>Inhalt6</td>
          <td>Inhalt5</td>
          <td>Inhalt6</td>
          <td>Inhalt5</td>
          <td>Inhalt6</td>
          <td>Inhalt5</td>
          <td>Inhalt6</td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
          <!--Untertabelle2-->
          <tr class="table2">
            <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
            <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
            <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
            <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
            <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
            <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
            <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
            <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
            <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="table2">
            <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
            <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </dd>
      <dt id="sh_january">Headline2</dt>
      <dd>125153226262</dd>
    </dl>
  </article>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(this).parents().next("tbody").find(".table2").each ...
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row "Animations are not supported on table-rows". Wrap the content in `td` inside a `div` and use `slideDown` on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(".inhalt").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('table2_active');
   $(this).parent().next('tr').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('table2')) {
            $(this).slideDown(300)
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```