# ReactJS - use slideDown (toggle) on a table row?

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have a table in React (JSX), and I want to toggle some of the rows (even multiple) by clicking on a row above them.

It's easy to just disappear them, but how can I do it smoothly (slideDown and slideUp)?

Min-height doesn't seem to be working and I also cannot wrap entire tr into a div since it's in React. Thanks.

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>main row - onclick toggle the rows under</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>           
      <tr>
          <td>show only if clicked on the row above (smoothly)</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>show only if clicked on the first row (smoothly)</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: It seems that [animations are not supported on table rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row).

Comment: Yes I know this, but for sure somebody had to find some clever workaround.

Comment: I had the similar issue and I ended up using div's instead of table.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you!

Use `state` to track the click and use the css to animate the `height` change.

Check this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pranesh_ravi/x7q88qpe/1/